# How does Python3's venv differ from virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm a long-time user of the [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Python packages.

How does virtualenv differ from Python3's built-in [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? Or is virtualenv built on, or incorporate, venv?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is python package virtualenv necessary when I use python 3.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971443/is-python-package-virtualenv-necessary-when-i-use-python-3-3)

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least Python3's venv doesn't have `postactivate` hook – you have to add any custom environment variables and other stuff to `activate`.