# Virtualenv - Python 3 - Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install virtualenv for Python 3 on Ubuntu 64bit 14.04.

I have installed pip for Python3 using:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

and everything works fine. Now though I am trying to use virtualenv command to actually create the environment and getting the error that it is not install (i guess because I haven't installed it for Python 2 and that is what it is trying to use)

How do I use the virtualenv for Python 3?  I have searched the documentation but can't see where it says what to do.

Comment: Nevermind.  Found this on ask ubuntu

http://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had the same issue coming from development environments on OS X where I could create Python 3 virtual environments by simply invoking `virtualenv` and the path to the target directory. You should be able to create a Python 3.x virtual environment in one of two ways:

1. Install `virtualenv` from the PyPi as you've done (`$ pip3 install virtualenv`), then by calling it as a module from the command line:

   `$ python3 -m virtualenv /path/to/directory`
2. Use the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html) module, which you can install through `apt-get`. (Note that Python 3.3 is when this module was introduced, so this answer assumes you're working with at least that):

   `$ sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv`

   Then you can set up your virtual environment with

   `$ pyvenv-3.4 /path/to/directory`

   and activate the environment with

   `$ source /path/to/directory/bin/activate`

You might also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971443/is-python-package-virtualenv-necessary-when-i-use-python-3-3), which discusses differences between the `venv` module and `virtualenv`. Best of luck!

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv returns an error:

E: Unable to locate package python3.4-venv

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.4-venv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.4-venv'

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why you weren't able to download the package. Verified I was able to install the `pyvenv-3.4` using Ubuntu's official docker repo for 14.04. You might need to first sync your package lists first (`sudo apt-get update`).

Answer (score 20):

in addition to all the answers, you can use the following command.

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.5
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use this command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Answer (score 4):

The `venv` became [standard library from python3 v3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html).  So if you get more recent python3 version, this can always done by:

```
  python3 -m venv <path-or-name-of-virtualenv>
  # choose correct python3, which is the name of your python3 cmd
```

No need to install or download anything before hand, when succeeded, pip3 will come with the virtualenv just created.  By this way, on most Linux, it will print out message to tell you what to do, for example it need `python3.4-venv`.

To active the virtualenv

```
 source <path-to-the-virtualenv>/bin/activate
 # then to deactive it:
 deactivate
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as a point of clarification if you are on ubuntu 14.04.1, the `python3.4-venv` package is not available (though it is in 14.04.5)

You can get around this by installing the `python-virtualenv` package and creating virtualenvs via one of the methods described in the other answers:

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

or

```
virtualenv envname --python=python3.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow below commands:

step-1 `pip3 install virtualenv` (if using python3)

step-2 `mkdir ~/my_environment` (dir where you want to create your vir-env)

step-3 `python3 -m virtualenv ~/my_environment`

step-4 `source ~/my_environment/bin/activate`

Done!!

I would rather suggest to create an alias for activating this vir-env on bashrc

step-1 `vim ~/.bashrc`

step-2 `alias myenv='source ~/my_environment/bin/activate'` #add this line at the bottom

step-3 :`wq` #save the file using

step-4 `source ~/.bashrc`

step-5 `myenv` #check your shortcut(alias)

Voyla Done!!