# Cant find django module . import error

Tags: python, django, pip

I have installed Django and it is already in the package. But when i run python manage.py runserver.I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: show please, `pip freeze | grep Django`

Comment: Django==1.11.2  this version

Comment: and next `python -m django`

Comment: No module named django

Comment: `pip -V; python -V` show version please

Comment: pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.5: No such file or directory

Comment: try `python3 manage.py check`

Comment: same error as stated in the questions

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip; pip install --upgrade django`

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you using a virtual environment? Did you change anything to make `python` point to Python 3.5? Usually I'd expect it to point to Python 2 unless you are in a virtual environment.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I have pointed python to 3.5 . I am working on django-channels thats why python 3.5

Comment: i had point to 3.5 in bashrc

Comment: how did you point it, try to install virtualenv, [virtualenv-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934032/virtualenv-python-3-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit) and run pip inside the virual env

Comment: getting the same error