# Unable to install django on python version 3.5?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

I have Python 3.5 so I think pip is already installed on my system. The website says:

> pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org, but you'll need to upgrade pip.

Now, I downloaded the `get-pip.py` and put it in `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5`. After that I ran the command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files\Python 3.5
C:\Program Files\Python 3.5>python get-pip.py
```

Here is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

So, I guess pip is working fine and the Django website recommends that I install virtualenv for which I ran the command `pip install virtualenv` but nothing has happened after that for about half an hour.

Am I missing something? Have I made a silly mistake? Please don't be rude about it as I am new to Python and Django.

**EDIT**: I am stuck at `pip install virtualenv`. Nothing happens after that.

**UPDATE**: I left out virtualenv and directly typed `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5>pip install Django` but it does not do anything either.

I have also used `C:\WINDOWS\system32>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts"` to add the Path variable.

Should I uninstall Python and do a fresh install?

Thanks.

Comment: Try pip3 and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285508/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-4-on-windows

Comment: @dmitryro on writing this command `python -m pip install -U pip`. It says `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages`.

What do I do now?

Comment: Your pip is already there - as of version 3.4 it's a part of distribution, so you can run ***pip install --upgrade virtualenv*** - and if this fails - download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv , unpack and install from source.

Comment: Thanks.
When I run `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5>pip install --upgrade virtualenv`. The cursor keeps blinking and nothing else happens. How long is it supposed to take?

I feel bad about not being able to install it using pip. Is there no way to no why is it happening?

Comment: I am pretty sure that python3 uses(packaged with it): `python3 -m venv myvenv` where myenv is the directory. I have to use `virtualenv` on 2.7. And yes, pip was already installed. try doing `pip freeze` to see all of your installed (external) packages

Comment: @tenwest So, I am supposed to type `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5>python3 -m venv myvenv`?

Comment: @tenwest I got `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It's probably just python , not python3 as this is the only interpreter you have - so try installing it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv pip gets stuck as your local machine has some memory not sufficient to run virtualenv, so some cleanup might be helpful

Comment: @SanJeet Singh as dmitryro says, just use `python`...also, virtualenv is included as `venv` since python3.3. that may be why pip is having trouble.  Rather than installing manually, I  would use what's bundled, but thats me. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971443/is-python-package-virtualenv-necessary-when-i-use-python-3-3

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527958/python-virtualenv-questions

Comment: @dmitryro and tenwest I have updated the question to add more details. :)

Comment: There's still an option of getting fresh ***setuptools*** from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and once ***easy_install*** is set, try ***easy_intall virtualenv*** and see, if it still not moving on. As I mentioned, you can install ***virtualenv*** from source using ***setup.py*** and see what's going on during the instillation. There's no need to reinstall Python.

Comment: Try using pip install ... --verbose to get more verbose output. Also virtualenv now is a part of python and it doesn't work with 3.x, use python -m venv (maybe you should install it)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in unlinked `pip` command for Windows cmd. To resolve this issue on Linux, the most common way is to link executable from directory where it lives to `/usr/bin` by `ln -s` command.

I dont't know how to do this in Windows, but one simple way to run `pip` without linking is to run it directly in folder, where it's `exe` file exists. By default on Windows it should be in `\path\to\python_directory\Scripts`. So in your case command `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts\pip.exe install django` should work.

**Edit 1**

And I see another issue here - as you have installed Python globally (in `Program Files`) - in order to install packages throug `pip`, you should run `cmd` as Administrator, otherwise you will get `PermissionError`